# A part of an object is not visible in the camera view - how can I fix it?

Tags: camera

[image]

After all i've done the works, but suddenly when im rendering
the plane object in my works wont show up fully.
And maybe the problem is in the camera perspective, or I dont know what happened.
Plese anyone who knows tell me how to fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: it should be the view clipping or the camera clipping, you should check these two

Comment: @LungguhIbrahim, please do not use all capitals in your titles.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for answering my question. I'll check it out. And sorry about my titles.

Comment: Im still learning blender, btw. please give me advices.

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thank you so much for helping me. Its really work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check camera clipping settings. Try to increase the End value.

[image]

Comment: Yes brother. Thank you so much.